# why does one react project use .bind(this) method but another react project does not use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did 2 tutorials on using REACT. "to-do-app" is a django/react project while "robofriends" is a purely react project. "to-do-app" uses .bind(this) for its functions while "robofriends" does not use this method. While i understand why the .bind method is needed, i do not understand why "robofriends" was able to work without binding its functions.

to-do app (apps.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todoList:[],
      activeItem:{
        id:null,
        title:"",
        completed:false
      },
      editing:false,
    }
    this.fetchTasks=this.fetchTasks.bind(this)
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchTasks()
  }

  fetchTasks(){
    console.log('fetching')
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list/')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>
      this.setState({todoList:data})
      )
  }

  handleChange(e){
    const name=e.target.name;
    const value=e.target.value;
    console.log('Name', name)
    console.log('Value', value)
    this.setState({
      activeItem:{
        ...this.state.activeItem,
        title:value
      }
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('ITEM', this.state.activeItem)

    var url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-create/'
    fetch(url, {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-type':'application/json',
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(this.state.activeItem)
    }).then((response) =>{
      this.fetchTasks()
      this.setState({
       activeItem:{
        id:null,
        title:"",
        completed:false
      }
      })
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('ERROR', error)
    })

  }

  render(){
    const tasks=this.state.todoList
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div id="task-container">

          <div id="form-wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="form">
              <div className="flex-wrapper">
                <div style={{flex:6}}>
                  <input onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Add task" />
                </div>
                <div style={{flex:1}}>
                  <input id="submit" className="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="Add" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div id="list-wrapper">
            {tasks.map((task, index)=>{
              return(
                <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                  <div style={{flex:7}}>
                    <span>{task.title}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{flex:1}}>
                    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Edit</button>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{flex:1}}>
                    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark delete">-</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                )
            })}
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

robofriends(apps.js)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CardList from '../components/Cardlist';
// import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
import './App.css';
import Scroll from '../components/Scroll';
import ErrorBoundary from '../components/ErrorBoundary';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            robots:[],
            searchfield:''
        } //a state is what changes in an app
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(users => this.setState({robots:users}))
    }



// remember to use => for functions you create yourself. 
    onSearchChange=(event) => {
        this.setState({searchfield:event.target.value})
    }

    render(){
        const {robots, searchfield}=this.state;
        const filteredRobots=robots.filter(robot=>{
            return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
        })
        if (!robots.length){
            return <h1>Loading</h1>
        }else{
    return(
        <div className='tc'>
            <h1 className='f1'>Robofriends</h1>
            <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
            <Scroll>
            <ErrorBoundary>
            <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
            </ErrorBoundary>
            </Scroll>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
}   

 export default App;
```

robofriends 'searchbox.js'

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox=({searchChange})=>{
    return (
        <div className='pa2'>
            <input 
                className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
                type='search' 
                placeholder='search robots' 
                onChange={searchChange}
            />
        </div>
        );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetchTasks(){
```

if you define a function like this, then you need to `.bind(this)`

as this will lose the context of `this` of `class`, to maintain it we need to use `.bind(this)`

---

But if you use below one then no need to bind, it maintains the context of `this`, so no need of using `.bind(this)`

> Arrow functions do not bind their own this, instead, they inherit the
>   one from the parent scope, which is called "lexical scoping"

```
fetchTasks = () => {
```

### For more detail : **[DO READ](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)**

Hope the below snippet will help you get understanding :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name : "Vivek"
    }
    this.withBound = this.withBound.bind(this);
  }
  
  withoutBound() {
    console.log(this.state.name)
  }

  withBound() {
    console.log(this.state.name)
  }

  withFatArrow = () => {
    console.log(this.state.name)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          Check the console on click:
          <br/><br/>
          <button onClick={this.withoutBound}>Without Bind</button>
          <br/><br/>
          <button onClick={this.withBound}>With Bind</button>
          <br/><br/>
          <button onClick={this.withFatArrow}>Fat Arrow</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain *why*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, was creating demo that took time, now you can check.